# FB Graph Api FB.getLoginStatus wrapper function returning undefined

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wrote a wrapper function for the `FB.getLoginStatus` that is defined as follows:

```
this.isLoggedInFB = function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.status == 'connected')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(response.status =='not_authorized'){
            return true;
        else{
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Whenever I make the following alert

```
alert(myClass.isLoggedInFB());
```

I get `undefined`.

When I add an alert within the body of `isLoggedInFB` to see if `FB` is defined I get:

```
[Object object]
```

which tells me that it `FB.init` has been called, which is confusing because
that is the only thing that I thought could have gone wrong.

Finally, I made an alert to see if I mistyped the name or that my name-spacing was wrong by doing

```
alert(myClass.isLoggedInFB);
```

and I got the correct function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the function isLoggedInFB does not return any value. if you need to get the response data back you need to return a value like this:

```
var connected = 0;
this.isLoggedInFB = function() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if(response.status == 'connected')
        {
            connected = 1;
            return true;
        }
        else if(response.status =='not_authorized'){
        {
            connected = 1;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            connected = 0;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return connected;
}
```

Comment: @Volkan_Ulukut so I just defined the callback function without actually writing the return statement of isLoggedInFB?

Comment: @Volkan_Ulukut also, with your implementation, my `return <boolean>` statements are unnecessary, no?

Comment: your anonymous function does not have a return statement. the callback function of FB.getLoginStatus can not return its vale to the parent function unless you define a global variable like i did. and yes your return true/false statements are not necessary.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut: Your function is not dealing with the “problem” asynchronism introduces here either. At the moment your method `isLoggedInFB` returns, `connected` will still have the same value as before; it will only get updated when the call is finished and the callback function is run.

Comment: true. the very reason the callback is there is to let you add your code once you get the connected status.